# Может ли обладатель золотого значка сам добавить метку на вопрос, отметить его как дубликат и потом снять метку?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Пусть есть участник у которого есть золотой знак допустим по `javascript`-у. Вот он гуляет по вопросам и видит вопрос с меткой `reactjs`, но без метки `javascript`. Вспоминмает, что где-то он уже видел такой вопрос. Так вот, он может сам добавить метку, отметить его как дубликат и потом снять метку?

Если нет, то вопроса впринципе нет) Хотелось бы только узнать, а что ему помешает

Если да, то получается, что участник с золотым значком, как и модераторы может абсолютно любой вопрос, единолично закрыть как дубликат путём таких вот мелких манипуляций. Если это так, то это как-то странно что ли... Т.е. понятно, что, если человек, дошёл до золотого значка, то скорее всего он очень хорошо себе представляет как работает сайт и вряд ли будет закрывать как дубликат вопросы направо и налево. Но из всего этого вытекает абсолютная бессмысленность привелегий в других золотых значках. Уж тогда лучше дать за любой золотой значок всего 1 привилегию - иметь право закрывать любой вопрос как дубликат

Comment: [Can't single-handedly reopen a dupehammered Q after editing gold tag to another gold tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310784/282647)

Comment: Нет, закрыть не сможет....... и вот я считаю, что это (возможность поставить метку и закрыть), как раз, не странно, а вполне логично. Но он лишён этой возможности. Вот это как раз и странно

Comment: @Grundy Блин такие вопросы надо сразу иметь в переводе на русский :) Спасибо)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну я бы поспорил) Если дать такую возможность, то у юзера будет абсолютная власть в дубликатах. Но и это обходится на самом деле, т.к. например ты можешь меня в чате где-то попросить поставить метку, а потом закрыть единолично. Но это уже будет сговором, а я не знаю такой сговор наказуем или нет

Comment: @EzioMercer ну и что власть в дубликатах? ну если будет метка - итак человек будет закрывать дубликаты в любом случае. В этом и смысл золотой метки как бэ ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯    А если он закрывает вообще всё подряд...начал какой-то крестовы поход - то это (если это неоправданно) наказуемо в итоге

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Так ты тогда можешь зайти в вопросы, где ты не разбираешься и посчитать что два каких-то вопроса дубликаты, когда как это будет не так. Добавишь свою метку, закроешь и потом уберёшь свою метку и вуаля испорченный вопрос, который надо открывать голосованием, а это трата времени

Comment: Золотая метка потому что человек не разбирается?))) кек. ...............открыть всегда можно вопрос - например тех же модераторов попросить...................ну а если, гипотетически, на всех вопросах будет метка для золотого молота - то он так же может всё назакрывать "не разбираясь в вопросе". Тогда надо все молоты изъять, чтобы не было казусов

Comment: Да не золотая метка в том что человек не разбирается, а поставить свою золотую метку в вопросы, в которых не разбираешься)) Ну я и сказал, что можно открыть, просто время займёт лишнее как для автора, так и для того, кто хотел ответить уже)) На счёт твоего гипотетического примера - ну тут и невозможно спорить, конечно, ты там абсолютно прав. А вот то что человек имеющий всего 1 золотую метку может закрыть дубликатом любой вопрос - это намного реалистичнее, т.к. не предусмотреть такое ограничение - вполне допустимо. И не будь такого ограничения в других золотых знаках уже не было бы смысла